# How to setup my article relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to make a article model.

```
A article belongs_to country
A article belongs_to region
A article belongs_to accomodation
```

So i want create listing like...give me articles from region X, give me articles from accomodation X.

The url structure looks like this:

```
/en/italy/articles
/en/italy/tuscany/articles
/en/italy/tuscany/accomodation_x/articles
ect
```

It is possibly in the a future that article has nothing todo with a accomodation, country or accomodation. By example company news ect

The url structure looks like this:

```
/en/articles
```

And on my homepage i want a show all new articles, with different paths. Point root_path of articles but also to the country_region_articles paths.

What is the best approach to setup the db relationsships?

Thanks..

remco

Comment: make sure you spell accommodation correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check these two casts too. On tagging and virtual attributes:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/167-more-on-virtual-attributes
http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any content strategy in your question so my answer may be biased.

In common sense an article may be about an accommodation or completely not. It may be related to a region without specific accommodation. Or it may be about a country with nothing to do with either region or accommodation.

In this case, tagging would be much better than hard association.

Another point is, either association or tagging can has nothing to do with URL. You are not required to use nested url with association.